# Starting neo4j gives exception saying "Address 127.0.0.1:7687 is already in use, cannot bind to it"

Tags: java, neo4j

While starting neo4j browser from an Ubuntu terminal by running `./bin/neo4j`, the following error is occurring. How can I solve this error?

> ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@bdc8014' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
>   cause exception "Address 127.0.0.1:7687 is already in use, cannot bind
>   to it.". Starting Neo4j failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@bdc8014' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
>   cause exception "Address 127.0.0.1:7687 is already in use, cannot bind
>   to it.". org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j
>   failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@bdc8014' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
>   cause exception "Address 127.0.0.1:7687 is already in use, cannot bind
>   to it.".  at
>   org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:219)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
>   Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@bdc8014' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
>   cause exception "Address 127.0.0.1:7687 is already in use, cannot bind
>   to it.".  at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory,
>   /home/app42admin/neo4jcommunityedition/neo4j-community-3.4.0-alpha01/data/databases/graph.db
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
>     ... 5 more Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException:
>   Component 'org.neo4j.bolt.transport.NettyServer@3e850122' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
>   cause exception "Address 127.0.0.1:7687 is already in use, cannot bind
>   to it.".  at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:84)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.neo4j.helpers.PortBindException: Address
>   127.0.0.1:7687 is already in use, cannot bind to it.  at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newIOException(Errors.java:117)     at
>   io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.bind(Socket.java:285)    at
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doBind(AbstractEpollChannel.java:696)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollServerSocketChannel.doBind(EpollServerSocketChannel.java:70)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1283)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:989)
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:254)
>     at
>   io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:365)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)>    at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
>     at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:309)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2017-11-15 09:54:42.077+0000
>   INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request

Answer (score 0):

The root error is `Address 127.0.0.1:7687 is already in use, cannot bind to it`.

So you already have something on your computer that is using the port `7687`.

Do you have an other Neo4j instance that is running?
Or do you have an other server that i using the port `7687`?

Comment: Thanku for ur answer . I removed this error . I have another question. - no modication is taking place on my localhost neo4j browser after running the java program

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'no modication is taking place on my localhost neo4j browser after running the java program' ... If it's unrelated to this question, can you open a new one ?

Comment: I mean any CRUD operations made through java , doesn't show on my neo4j browser . How to do this?

Comment: do you commit your transactions ?

Comment: How do you solve the error ? I have the same error.

Comment: Check in your processes that you have not an other runing Neo4j  server, or that you have an other server that uses the same ports